# View State Is Invalid By Use this.Form.Submit in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, proxy, viewstate, iis-7.5, form-submit

View State Is Invalid By Use this.Form.Submit in IIS 7.5
A new WebSite, we test it on the IIS 6.0, it's OK.
But when we test on the IIS 7.5, the "View State Is Invalid" is displayed.

The error information:
    Port: 3739
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)
    ViewState: /wEPDwUJOTM1[***]MCIg...
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

The [***] has been deleted becasue is too long, but the "MCIg..." is in the log.

I Check the source and find the next part:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_search" runat="server" CssClass="submitbutton" 
   OnClientClick="javascript:this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();"
   Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="Btn_search_Click" />
```

When i delete the [OnClientClick="javascript:this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();"] and delete [UseSubmitBehavior="False"]. The page will run Ok.
It look like [this.form.submit] cause the error.
But i test as follow
 1. IIS 6.0, No Proxy , IE6.0 or IE8.0 Test OK.
 2. IIS 6.0, Use Proxy , IE6.0 or IE8.0 Test OK.
 3. IIS 7.5, Use Proxy, IE6.0 or IE8.0 Test OK.
 4. IIS 7.5, No Proxy, IE6.0 or IE8.0 Test Error.

Do any one know why, use Proxy is OK ,otherwise error.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is probably __doPostBack(). Take a look here:

[Explicit __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746270/explicit-dopostback)

Your variant probably should look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_search" runat="server" CssClass="submitbutton" 
   OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('Btn_search','');return false;"
   Text="Search" OnClick="Btn_search_Click" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is about the proxy, why in with the proxy setted in the IE ,the test is ok.and without proxy it's error

Comment: I see. I guess it won't change anything but did you try changing your way of submitting the form to use __doPostBack anyway? Maybe the post data will change somehow and the error will disappear. It would take you just a couple minutes, so maybe it's worth a try.